# How can i resolve receiving a HTTP 525 response error every morning at 04:00 for around 10 minutes

Tags: laravel, nginx, https, cloudflare

Every morning at 04:00 for around 10 mins our system reports 525 response errors.

We have a Cloudflare ssl,the site is running on a DigitalOcean box (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). The application is built on Laravel and running Nginx.

There is nothing unusual about whats happening at 04:00 than at any other time of the day.
Traffic is normal (extremely light), no spikes in CPU, RAM, Disk I/O, Network etc.. and all running well within their limits. The only thing we see is that CPU usage drops in the same period due to not having anything to process.

There are no backups or other scheduled events running at this time either.

I run some ping/http response tests and log them just to see if theres any network issues, ping tests are all good, but I see the 525 results during the time frame in question.

Heres a copy of the headers we get with the error;

```
content-length 0
CF-Cache-Status DYNAMIC
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache
NEL {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server cloudflare
CF-RAY 75ce8ebd0df057c4-IAD
Report-To {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=mQCWwEx9BjnyWc9eZHKliK2WKy3dFt1%2F%2FZFHqu0L95%2BIIOqwdgnlROO9EEf1tt8itCL6yvRQKs%2FoKjEzvtFIEnM"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
X-Twilio-WebhookAttempt 1
X-Twilio-WebhookRetriable false
Date Thu, 20 Oct 2022 03:09:56 GMT
```

I have run some cipher tests and it shows some weak ciphers but surely the issue would happen all the time and not just for a 10 minute window every day?

Has anyone come across anything similar where it happens pretty much every day at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Some providers use those kinds of hours as maintenance windows so you should double check either cloudflare or digitalocean if there's something like that that they would do.

Comment: Sidenote, and for a little humour, I find it funny that your server is self-aware enough to know that 4 in the morning is indeed ["too early"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/425)

Comment: @TimLewis i can see the tumbleweeds entering stage left ;)

Comment: @apokryfos thats my hunch as well, just seems a little too coincidental that it happens every day at the same time.